# Remove more from prestashop Main Menu 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I would like to remove more link from Prestashop main Menu. I'd like to list for categories but it only list three and the other one is displayed in a drop-down. I just want to list all four. I've tried going through the code but I havenot found where to remove it

Answer (score 4):

in the js file :

```
    var max_link =3;
    var items = $('.topmenu .menu ul#top-menu > li');
    var surplus = items.slice(max_link, items.length);
    surplus.wrapAll('<li class="more_menu ttmenu"><div class="top-menu sub-menu clearfix">');
    $('.more_menu').prepend('<a href="#" class="level-top">More</a>');
    $('.more_menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('div').addClass('shown-link');
    })
    $('.more_menu').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).children('div').removeClass('shown-link');
    });
```

change max_link

Comment: In your theme directory you should have /assets/js/custom.js file. Inside that file, change var max_link to upper value.